# In a div container filled with 2 child divs inside, how do I give priority for one to show over the other while both still truncating to an ellipsis?

Tags: html, css

In a simple div container, how do I tell one of the child div's message to display and take up the usable space first, with the remaining being allocated to the other, "lesser priority" div? I feel that I've accomplished that part, the lesser priority div only displaying as much as it can without taking up the other child's space, truncating itself with an ellipsis when necessary. However, my current solution doesn't allow the higher priority div to truncate into an ellipsis if it itself is too large and cant fit in the space.

My current solution that describes where I'm at above is as follows:

```
<div>
    <div
        style=
        {{
            whiteSpace='nowrap'
            overflow='hidden'
            textOverflow='ellipsis'
        }}
    >
        {message1}
    </div>
    <div
        style=
        {{
            whiteSpace='nowrap'
            overflow='hidden'
            textOverflow='ellipsis'
            flex='1 0 auto'
        }}
    >
        {message2}
    </div>
</div>
```

To clarify, there are 3 cases of interest:

CASE 1:

Div1 and Div2 fit into the desired space, no truncating necessary (works as desired)
[image]

CASE 2:

Div2 takes up significant space, and thus Div1 must truncate to allow Div2 to fit first before filling available space
(works as desired with `flex='1 0 auto'`)
[image]

CASE 3:

Div2 is too big for the space, meaning Div1 should not show at all and Div2 should truncate when it reaches max available space
(does not work as Div2 will not truncate)
[image]

```html
<div style="
        display: flex;
        direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-top: 15px;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 0.9em;
      ">
      
  <div style="
          white-space: nowrap; 
          overflow: hidden; 
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
        ">
    111111111111, 
  </div>
  
  <div style="
          white-space: nowrap;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
        ">
    
222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you set flex-basis on the priority div to its native width and you don't let it shrink to fit the parent div.

One way to fix this is to specify your child flex properties like so:

For the div 1:

```
flex: 1 1 0;
```

And for the div 2 (priority div):

```
flex: 0 1 auto;
```

Working sample:

```html
<div style="
        display: flex;
        direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-top: 15px;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 0.9em;
      ">
      
  <div style="
          white-space: nowrap; 
          flex: 1 1 0;
          overflow: hidden; 
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
        ">
    111111111111111111111111
  </div>
  
  <div style="
          white-space: nowrap;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          flex: 0 1 auto;
        ">
    
22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="
        display: flex;
        direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-top: 15px;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 0.9em;
      ">
      
  <div style="
          white-space: nowrap; 
          flex: 1 0 auto;
          overflow: hidden; 
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
        ">
    111111111111111111111111
  </div>
  
  <div style="
          white-space: nowrap;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
        ">
    
22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
  </div>
</div>
```

You just need to flex: 1 0 auto from div 2 and add into div 1 that's it.